# Class constructor parameters incompatible even though they overlap

Tags: typescript

I've simplified my actual code to pinpoint the problem. Here's my constructor type:

```
interface FooCtor {
    new (element: Element): any;
}
```

...and here is my class definition:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {}
}
```

For some reason, I can't assign `Foo` to a variable that expects `FooCtor`:

```
let ctor: FooCtor;
ctor = Foo;
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'FooCtor'.
  Types of parameters 'element' and 'element' are incompatible.
    Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 107 more. ts(2322)
```

I also tried this:

```
interface FooCtor {
    new<T extends Element> (element: T): any;
}
```

...but got the same result.

Everything that `Element` can do, `HTMLElement` can do too, because *it's an extension* of it. It seems that TypeScript expects and exact type match. Why is that?

TypeScript playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0GEzqsgbwCgBIECAd2QAoIAbCAWwnAC5kBRB58ASnbggAngG4iAXyJEEdOAGc5aTISLI1yBOhBywUAK4JcUWtxZh2ACQAqAWQAyXJmd6FJkogzAaj7DNiNihnjIALxK6CJAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct. The contract of `Foo` is that it receives an `HTMLElement`, but the contract of `FooCtor` is that it only requires an `Element`. Let's carry on from your code:

```
let ctor: FooCtor;
ctor = Foo;
new ctor(someSVGElement); // Would be allowed
```

That's equivalent to:

```
new Foo(someSVGElement);  // Is an error
```

...but `Foo` can't accept an `SVGElement`, it requires `HTMLElement`.

If you want to use `Foo` where `FooCtor` is required, you could modify `Foo` to accept `Element`, and then in places where it needs `HTMLElement` have it use a type guard to check that it actually has one. For example:

```typescript
interface FooCtor {
    new (element: Element): any;
}

function isHTMLElement(element: Element): element is HTMLElement {
    return "accessKey" in element;
}
class Foo {
    constructor(public element: Element) {}

    get accessKey(): string {
        const { element } = this;
        if (isHTMLElement(element)) {
            return element.accessKey;
        }
        // Throw an error or return a default
        throw new Error(`element is not an HTMLElement`);
    }
}

let ctor: FooCtor;
ctor = Foo;

const f1 = new Foo(document.body);
console.log(f1.accessKey); // ""
const f2 = new Foo(document.getElementById("some-svg-element")!);
console.log(f2.accessKey); // Error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#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)

Live JavaScript version:

```js
/*
interface FooCtor {
    new (element: Element): any;
}
*/

function isHTMLElement(element/*: Element*/)/*: element is HTMLElement*/ {
    return "accessKey" in element;
}
class Foo {
    constructor(/*public */element/*: Element*/) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    get accessKey()/*: string*/ {
        const { element } = this;
        if (isHTMLElement(element)) {
            return element.accessKey;
        }
        // Throw an error or return a default
        throw new Error(`element is not an HTMLElement`);
    }
}

let ctor/*: FooCtor*/;
ctor = Foo;

const f1 = new Foo(document.body);
console.log(f1.accessKey); // ""
const f2 = new Foo(document.getElementById("some-svg-element")/*!*/);
console.log(f2.accessKey); // Error
```

```html
<svg id="some-svg-element"></svg>
```